# Using XCOM_PULL in a FileSenor filepath arguement?

Tags: airflow

I am really new to Airflow, so please forgive me if this is a dim question. I did search unsuccessfully on Stackoverlow to find a similar question.

I have a download stream task that waits for a file to download. I'd like to abstract the hardcoded filepath and retrieve the path, stored in an XCOM.

```
  t2 = FileSensor(
    task_id = 'waiting_for_file_download',
    poke_interval = 60 * 5,
    timeout = 60 * 10,
    mode = 'reschedule',
    filepath = {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids = 'downloaded_file', key = 'file_path') }} + 'transformed' + '_new.csv.gz'
  )
```

Is this possible?

Reading the [official filesensor documentation](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_api/airflow/contrib/sensors/file_sensor/index.html?highlight=filesensor#airflow.contrib.sensors.file_sensor.FileSensor.template_fields) did not really help me, as a newcomer.

I see there are two additional fields 1) templates 2) fs_conn_id

UPDATE
Reading the docs I can see a XCOM.get_one() however this is not working either:

```
filepath = XCom.get_one(
  execution_date = date.today(),
  dag_id = 'My_DAG',
  task_id = 'downloaded_file',
  key = 'file_path'
```

I see that other users use this in conjunction with **context, however, I do not know how you can use the context within the FileSenor()?

Comment: I have done some more reading and found a XCOM.get_one() function, however this is not working either.

Answer (score 0):

Since `filepath` is declared as a templated field in the `FileSensor` class, it's possible to use [Jinja](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/operators.html#jinja-templating) templating and perform the `xcom.pull()` during runtime.

I think you were only missing the fact that the Jinja syntax goes withing a string, try this:

```py
filepath = "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids = 'downloaded_file', key = 'file_path') }}" + 'transformed' + '_new.csv.gz'
```

Let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: thank you for your advice, unfortunately it does not work, I receive the following log error "INFO - Poking for file /None"

Comment: @dimButTries Try checking form the UI the resultant XCom of the upstream task you are trying to pull from (`downloaded_file`). If you click on that Task Instance >> Log >> XCom  do you see the expect key / value pair ? Make sure the key is actually called `file_path` as the arg you are providing within the Jinja in `filepath` arg.